# Why isn't finding the average by specific groups working using this SQL code?

Tags: sql, alter

Suppose we have the following table (called `numbers`):

```
Name A B C
Jon  1 3 0.33
Sue  4 4 1
Jon  5 5 1
```

I'd like to amend the table so that it includes a new column, `D`, which is the mean of column `C` specific to each individual. For instance, `Jon` appears twice and so the average of `C` for them is `0.33 + 1 / 2 = 0.665`. Hence, I want `0.665` to be added to `Jon`. The same principle applies to the other names in the database, so that the result is something like:

```
Name A B C    D
Jon  1 3 0.33 0.665
Sue  4 4 1    1
Jon  5 5 1    0.665
```

Any ideas how to do this? I tried `ALTER TABLE numbers ADD D DECIMAL(50, 2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS AVG(C) GROUP BY Name` but this didn't work.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`AVG()` is an aggregation function that works across rows.  The expressions for generated columns only work within one row, not across rows.

You can do this using a view (or perhaps with a user-defined function, depending on your database):

```
create view v_numbers as
    select n.*,
           avg(c) over (partition by name) as d
    from n;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is window functions:

```
SELECT
    name
    ,a
    ,b
    ,c
    ,avg(c) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS d
FROM
    numbers
;
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ph1QgxTfkt2Bxobgb1UkAo/1)**

Comment: Thank you - but is there a way to do this so that it amends the table? Because I want to later run other queries on the new table outputted in your answer

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You can use the query as a subquery.